# Making directed arrow start/stop outside the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     [every rectangle node/.style={draw},
     every circle node/.style={draw,double}]
     \draw [->](0,0) node[rectangle] {0} -- (1,2) node[circle] {1};
     \draw [->](1,2) node[circle] {1} -- (2,1) node[circle] {2};
     \draw [->](2,1) node[circle] {2} -- (2,-1) node[circle] {3};
     \draw [->](2,-1) node[circle] {3} -- (1,-2) node[circle] {4};
     \draw [->](1,-2) node[circle] {4} -- (0,0) node[rectangle] {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives rise to the following picture:

[image]

The arrow starts inside the square/circle and end inside the circle/square. How can the edges be made to start/stop at the boundary of the square/circle?

Comment: What is your minimal complete code? Can you put the \documentclass and the \usepackages?

Comment: @Sebastiano Updated the OP with the complete MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Place and name the nodes and then connect them using their name. TikZ automatically draws the lines to their borders then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

1. fill the nodes so that the arrows going inside aren't visible
2. use the `shorten >=...`  option to make the arrow head stop outside of the node

---

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     [every rectangle node/.style={draw,fill=white},
     every circle node/.style={draw,double,fill=white}]
     \draw [->,shorten >=0.35cm](0,0) node[rectangle] {0} -- (1,2) node[circle] {1};
     \draw [->,shorten >=0.35cm](1,2) node[circle] {1} -- (2,1) node[circle] {2};
     \draw [->,shorten >=0.35cm](2,1) node[circle] {2} -- (2,-1) node[circle] {3};
     \draw [->,shorten >=0.35cm](2,-1) node[circle] {3} -- (1,-2) node[circle] {4};
     \draw [->,shorten >=0.35cm](1,-2) node[circle] {4} -- (0,0) node[rectangle] {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively you could name your node and use them by their name instead of hard coded coordinates (this way you also avoid drawing each of the nodes twice which can look blurred in some pdf viewers):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
     [every rectangle node/.style={draw},
     every circle node/.style={draw,double}]
     \node[rectangle] (0) at (0,0) {0};
     \node[circle] (1) at (1,2) {1};
     \node[circle] (2) at (2,1) {2};
     \node[circle] (3) at (2,-1) {3};
     \node[circle] (4) at (1,-2) {4};
     
     \draw[->] (0) -- (1);
     \draw[->] (1) -- (2); 
     \draw[->] (2) -- (3); 
     \draw[->] (3) -- (4); 
     \draw[->] (4) -- (0);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work, TY! However, the 0.35cm seem like something that should be done with trial and error? That is also fine...however, are there automated ways that do not use such magic numbers?

Comment: @Tryer Yes, by not using hard coded coordinates for your  arrows and instead connect the nodes by giving them names and connecting these names

Comment: @Tryer If you'd only draw the nodes and connect them later you'd also avoid drawing every node twice.

Comment: TY! I was thus far using GeoGebra/GraphViz (quite painfully) thus far for this process. Glad to try to use Tikz from here on!

Comment: @Tryer Have fun with TikZ!

Answer (score 3):

You should place the nodes first while giving them a name.

In

```
\node (1) at (1, 2) {1};
```

the `(1)` specifies the node's name. This name can later be used as in a coordinate specification. When used with many path operations (like [`--`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.--)) TikZ automatically starts (or ends) the line at the border of the specified node.

That's (more or less) the whole point of nodes!

The following

```
\node[rectangle] (0) at (0, 0) {0};
\node[circle]    (1) at (1, 2) {1};
\draw[->] (0) -- (1);
```

will connect `0` and `1` at their border (while adding an arrow tip at the and without it crossing the border either).

In the code below I'm using the [`edge` operation](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.12) (which defaults to a `--`) which makes it a bit easier to connect many nodes with lines of a common property (here `->`) but also allow each edge to be different by using the optional argment, say `edge[<-, green]`.

---

I guess you were going from [these examples in the manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/every:node) but they are bad when it comes to actual node usage.

Even, the `every <shape> node` styles are rarely more useful than defining properly named styles.

This is why I've defined the styles `start` and `vertex` (use better names – I don't know what these nodes represent) where even the shape of the node is declared.

If you later find yourself having to change all vertices to a different shape you only need to change the `vertex` style instead of going through all `circle` nodes.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  start/.style={rectangle, draw},
  vertex/.style={circle, draw, double}]
\node[start]  (0) at (0, 0) {0};
\node[vertex] (1) at (1, 2) {1};
\node[vertex] (2) at (2, 1) {2};
\node[vertex] (3) at (2,-1) {3};
\node[vertex] (4) at (1,-2) {4};
\path[->] (0) edge (1)
          (1) edge (2)
          (2) edge (3)
          (3) edge (4)
          (4) edge (0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right in where I picked these from. I scanned the manual up and down to see if they cover my test case but they did not. Hence my post here.

Comment: There are multiple ways to place nodes on the paper without the use of explicit coordinates (like `(1, 2)`) but that's a topic for another time (take a look at [matrices](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices) and the accompanying [`matrix` library](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix) as well as the [`positioning`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf.positioning) and the [`chains`](https://tikz.dev/library-chains) libraries.) There's also the `graphs` library (for an even shorter syntax than `edge`) and the `graphdrawing` library which both place and connect node but that becomes too complicated very fast.